# React Native with Firebase: Can anybody see where email is formatted incorrectly?

Tags: firebase, react-native

could I get a second pair of eyes on this.
Where is email formatted incorrectly as my React Native simulator is saying?

`LoginForm.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  onEmailChanged(text) {
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }

  onPasswordChange(text) {
    this.props.passwordChanged(text);
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.props;
    this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Email"
            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
            onChangeText={this.onEmailChanged.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.email}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            label="Password"
            placeholder="password"
            onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.password}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Login</Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email,
    password: state.auth.password
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  emailChanged,
  passwordChanged,
  loginUser
})(LoginForm);
```

`actions/index.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED } from './types';

export const emailChanged = text => {
  return {
    type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
    payload: text
  };
};

export const passwordChanged = text => {
  return {
    type: 'PASSWORD_CHANGED',
    payload: text
  };
};

export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS', payload: user });
      });
  };
};
```

`types.js`:

```
export const EMAIL_CHANGED = 'email_changed';
export const PASSWORD_CHANGED = 'password_changed';
```

`AuthReducer.js`:

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { email: '', password: '' };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

It looks like the error is coming from firebase but I have not found any documentation that is relevant to my error.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @PritishVaidya, the email address is badly formatted.

Comment: I couldn't get it, sorry, badly formatted like how, can you add a small example too?

Comment: @PritishVaidya, if I knew what the error meant by badly formatted, I would have corrected it. I have no clue why I am getting this error. Is there something wrong with my `types.js` file?

Comment: Okay , so the firebase throws incorrect email error.

Comment: @PritishVaidya, right, and I think it may be referring to this: `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you check the logs if the email is being set as correct before dispatching the login user action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179938/discussion-between-daniel-and-pritish-vaidya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some time of looking over the code, discussing the code with a colleague on here and trying different fixes.

Another colleague mentioned their own action creator issue that was similar to mine. So I decided to look at my `actions/index.js` file and sure enough if you take a look at `type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED'`, it should be `type: EMAIL_CHANGED`, no quotes required.

After this I refreshed the simulator attempted to login and had a `{type: "LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS", payload: Lk}` in console.